# The Parameter is Incorrect when trying to connect to AD using DirectoryEntry

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I am trying to connect to an AD using the `DirectoryEntry` .NET class. But I am getting an error

> The parameter is incorrect

when trying to access

```
DirectoryEntry.NativeObject
```

in order to force authentication.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason for this error, or how to identify what is wrong here?

Code snippet:

```
Dim deRoot As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
deRoot = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://SERVERNAME:PORT/DOMAINSTRING", "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer)
Dim obj As Object = deRoot.NativeObject
```

The issue happens when executing 3rd Line.

NOTE: The same works for many LDAP servers. Need to know what is the difference in this server or identify what needs to be passed to make this work.

Regards

Comment: Are you using port 636 or 3269 as the port? Even when using that, I found that specifying `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer` is not necessary. It figures it out. Try removing it.

Comment: Note that `New DirectoryEntry` does not actually make the connection. It waits until you actually do something with the object before it actually connects to the DC. That's why you get the error on the 3rd line.

Comment: It ended up to be the certificate which is causing the issue. We get this error.

**The certificate received from the remote server does not contain the expected name. It is therefore not possible to determine whether we are connecting to the correct server. The server name we were expecting is [servername]. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate** 

But when we add an host entry, this works fine. But the problem is that its an dynamic IP and the IP's keep changing.

Is there a way to bypass this when using `DirectoryEntry` class?

Comment: I read somewhere that `LDAPConnection` class has he ability to bypass this certificate error, but it will be really hard to implement this in out application.

Or Is there a way to make some changes in the webserver so that the host entry always points to the updated dynamic IP?

Comment: I've had cases where I connect using the domain name, but the certificate has the full name of the domain controller. In those cases, I connect using the domain controller name. Can you do the same? Is the certificate using the name of the DC rather than the domain name?

Comment: We tried all combinations but we were not able to make this work using `DirectoryEntry` class. We ended up creating a sample application to authenticate using `LDAPConnection` class. We were able to make this work by bypassing the certification validation. 
It boils down to this question - Is there a way I can ignore the Server Cert Verification using `DirectoryEntry` class.

Using `LDAPConnection`, we achieved this as below:

`

Comment: `LDAPConnectoin.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = AddressOf VerifyServerCertificateCallback
`

And the callback function will be


 `Private Function VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ByVal cert As LdapConnection, ByVal certificate As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate) As Boolean
     Return True
End Function
`

Comment: You have to match the server name you feed to `DirectoryEntry` with the domain name on the certificate. To examine the certificate, you can use a utility from DigiCert: https://www.digicert.com/util/ Run it and click on the 'Tools' tab, then 'Check Install'. For the 'Server Address' put in your domain DNS name, then 636 for the port. Then click 'Query Server'. When the certificate details pop up, look at the 'Subject Name'. Is that exactly what you put in for the 'Server Address'? If it's different, then use that name in your "LDAP://" string.

Comment: Also make sure the dates in the certificates are valid and that the issuer is trusted. If it's not trusted, you will need to import the root certificate into the Windows root certificates. I can help you with that if that's the case.

Comment: I am not that good at domains and servers but to summarize shortly, here is the problem: 
Both the server name and the name on certificate matches. Both are say "abc.com". We have load balancers in place and load balancer is having the server name as "abc.amazon.....com" because of which the certification validation is failing.

Comment: Do you have to use the load balancer? Can you target a specific DC directly?

Comment: We cannot take off the load balancer. Using `LDAPConnection` class, if we bypass the certificate validation, then we are able to connect to the LDAP  Server. But we do not have this option to bypass certificate validation using `DirectoryEntry`. Are there any options to disable/bypass the certificate validation when request is made through particular application? The application is written in .NET. This will help us to keep the existing code which uses `DirectoryEntry`, instead of having an overhead of rewriting the code using `LDAPConnection` class.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Not that I could find. DirectoryEntry is basically a wrapper around ActiveDs.dll, which is unmanaged C++ code. There must be a way to convince it that the certificate is fine. I'll write an answer with some details.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like your certificate for some reason.

The first step is to inspect the certificate. You can use a utility from DigiCert: http://www.digicert.com/util

Run it and click on the 'Tools' tab, then 'Check Install'. For the 'Server Address' put in your domain DNS name, then 636 for the port. Then click 'Query Server'. There are two things to look for:

1. Subject Name
2. Whether the certificate is trusted

You must be using the 'Subject Name' on the certificate to connect to AD. For example:

```
deRoot = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://{SubjectName}:PORT/DOMAINSTRING", "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer)
```

That 'Subject Name' might be the name of one of your domain controllers, like server1.domain.com. If you can use that, great. If you can't use it as is, then you can modify your hosts file so that whatever domain name shows in the 'Subject Name' points to the IP. Not ideal, but it may work.

The hosts file trick won't work if each server behind the load balancer is serving a different certificate. If that's happening, you're out of luck.

Also, the certificate must be trusted. It might be self-signed, for example. In that case, you must install the certificate on the machine making the call.

A clue to this is that every time an attempt is made, you'll see an error in the Windows System event log from 'Schannel' saying this:

> The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an
>   untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data
>   contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection
>   request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

The resolution to this depends on whether it is actually self-signed, or just signed by a Certification Authority that just isn't trusted on your machine. If this turns out to be the case, I can help.